# A person of station

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> I stand tall yet remain grounded.
>
> I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.
>
> I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.
>
> With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

Who am I?

**Hint:**

> There have been a couple answers that are on the right track. The clue about distraction can be interpreted more abstractly.

**Hint 2:**

> Disingenuous is my position, unrelated and unfounded.

**Hint 3:**

> If my ruse is revealed, it will certainly lead to litigation.

**Hint 4:**

> The answer is an open compound word formed from two words, and its literal definition is rarely used.

Comment: why it sounds like Shadow for me?

Comment: The last clue especially has eluded the answers so far.

Comment: Does any of this have to do with rot13(pbjf, tebhaq orrs, ohetref)?

Comment: @VirtualValentin No nothing to do with those.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is

> a piñata

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> Hoisted up on a rope, attached by the rope to a grounded object

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> It is a party game to hit a pinata, but the person is blinded and confused, perhaps frustrated.

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> Mainly pounded, but once on the ground I suppose it can be cut and stabbed. Perhaps when loading treats it is cut/stabbed.

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> The destruction of a pinata is often met with celebration.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Welcome to the site as well!

Comment: This is very specific.

Answer (score 5):

You are a

> punching(kicking) bag.

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> About head height, large base to ground it

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> Many people workout to distract themselves. They can bounce back to hit you if you're unaccustomed to using one. It hitting you could also cause aggravation.

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> It's purpose is this, cut/stabbed with rubber knives in martial arts courses

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> It finds it's purpose, and thus jubilation in serving it's purpose.

Comment: Not quite, but some good reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

**New Guess**

> You are a tree

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> Trees get tall but still are rooted to the earth

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> Trees can distract lightning

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> Trees are cut down an worked into stuff

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> Wood gets used for all sorts of fires

Title

> The top of a tree is called a crown

Old Guess:

> A candle
>  Candles are tall but are (supposed to be) standing solid in their place
>  The flickering can confuse or aggravate beings (Thinking of cats swatting at it)
>  A bit at a loss here. I've seen all of this happening to a candle but it's not the intended use.
>  Candles are lit for celebratory purposes

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely an

> **effigy**

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> Hoisted effigy

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> As a scarecrow

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> As a voodoo doll

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation

> Burnt for bonfire

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't specific enough with my clues. This fits well but wasn't quite what I had in mind.

Comment: Totally thought this was it - nice guess...

Comment: Thanks @Stiv, even with the added hint, I couldn’t move my mind off from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> A [lightning rod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_rod)?

I stand tall yet remain grounded:

> They stand above the surrounding structures to act as a lightning conductor and "remain grounded" to conduct the electricity to the ground safely.

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation:

> The hint suggests we can interpret distraction abstractly. They *distract* the lightning from hitting surrounding objects.

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded:

> This is the intention: they are hit/sliced by lightning...

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation:

> They are destined to draw potential fire away from surrounding structures.

Disingenuous is my position, unrelated and unfounded:

> Conventional wisdom says not to be the tallest/most conductive structure in a lightning storm yet lightning rods intentionally function like the best possible path to ground to protect other structures from being struck.

And the title:

> Could refer to power stations. Or to their elevated station.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> gong (musical instruments) ?.

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> About half of a person tall, perhaps more. Grounded and not easily
>  moving.

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> Since they define large rhythmic units, it is used to distract people
>  so that they know something is coming or happening, but also can lead
>  to confusion and aggravation when hitting too much.

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> It serves its purpose of being hit. Sometimes cut and stabbed to
>  change to a new surface.

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> During Asian's celebration (the *Lion dance*), the gongs are used continuously during
>  practice and celebration.

Comment: No, that doesn't quite fit with some of the clues.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a:

> Dummy?

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> Pretty straightforward here

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> During WWII, dummies were set up by the allies to confuse the Germans

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> Training dummies for different purposes

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> Dummies serve the purpose for either training, protecting or attacking someone and would obviously get some damage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're a

> SAND CASTLE

I stand tall yet remain grounded.

> sand castles can be tall, but are on the ground, (heck, made of ground)

I serve as a distraction, it can lead to confusion or aggravation.

> While making a sand castle, you could be so distracted that you don't feel yourself getting a sunburn - or dehydration, sun stroke, etc.

I am abused; cut, stabbed, and pounded.

> The methods of creating a sand castle

With jubilation, I am destined for immolation.

> Usually fun, at least for me, to see my sand castles get washed away by the rising tide

Title

> A person of station -  maybe Royalty? Lives in a castle

Last clue

> Open compound word
>  Sand castles usually aren't large enough or permanent enough to actually use them as a dwelling

Comment: Hmm, I would think that's closed compound.

Comment: I was just looking at a list of supposed open compound words. Never knew there was such a thing. It's all new to me. :)